# Jhipster export table

Tags: jhipster, jdl

Hello is that it is possible to export the table deja generer by jhipster in format jh also this https://jhipster.github.io/jdl-studio/

That is to say do the opposite way instead of import I want to export the schema of jhipster on my machine

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the last version of jhipster cli `4.5.1` you can generate it by providing `export-jdl` argument.

```
➜  ~ jhipster --help

  Usage: jhipster [command] [options]


  Commands:

    app                       Create a new JHipster application based on the selected options
    aws                       Deploy the current application to Amazon Web Services
    ci-cd                     Create pipeline scripts for popular Continuous Integration/Continuous Deployment tools
    client                    Create a new JHipster client-side application based on the selected options
    cloudfoundry              Generate a `deploy/cloudfoundry` folder with a specific manifest.yml to deploy to Cloud     Foundry
    docker-compose            Create all required Docker deployment configuration for the selected applications
    entity [name]             Create a new JHipster entity: JPA entity, Spring server-side components and Angular     client-side components
    export-jdl [jdlFile]      Create a JDL file from the existing entities
    heroku                    Deploy the current application to Heroku
    import-jdl [jdlFiles...]  Create entities from the JDL file passed in argument
    info                      Display information about your current project and system
    kubernetes                Deploy the current application to Kubernetes
    languages [languages...]  Select languages from a list of available languages. The i18n files will be copied to the /    webapp/i18n folder
    openshift                 Deploy the current application to OpenShift
    rancher-compose           Deploy the current application to Rancher
    server                    Create a new JHipster server-side application
    service [name]            Create a new Spring service bean
    upgrade                   Upgrade the JHipster version, and upgrade the generated application
    completion                Print command completion script

  Options:

    -h, --help     output usage information
    -d, --debug    enable debugger
    -V, --version  output the version number

  For more info visit https://jhipster.github.io

➜  ~
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a module currently being developed that will help: https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-jhipster-db-helper